# Rotation to Movement Vector2

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, vector, game-engine

I have a 2D GameObject with a component of Rigidbody 2d, and I want to move it forward based on its rotation (Rigidbody2D.rotation - z angle). How can i create movement Vector2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what forward is in your game..

Is forward up?

```
this.transform.position += this.transform.up * Time.deltaTime;
```

Is forward right?

```
this.transform.position += this.transform.right * Time.deltaTime;
```